# save c# object to disk

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I want to save/read an object to disk in c#. some of it's properties are not marked with [Serializable].
Is there any other way to save it?
I don't care about the format of the object on the disk, I only want to dump it to the disk and read it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could save it was XML with property names and their values, if it's a fairly simple object anyhow.

Comment: I have remove my anwer as it has been down voter even if it was correct. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596317/why-does-binary-serialization-require-the-object-to-be-marked-as-serializable

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the suggested XmlSerializer would be [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). It's a .net implementation of Google's protobuf written by a SO/StackExchange own Marc Gravell.
Note, you will have to have access to the objects since protobuf-net supports only custom classes that:

- are marked as data-contract
- have a parameterless constructor
- for Silverlight: are public

If that doesn't work for you, you could either write your own solution or, depending on your scope, use an object db like [eloquera](http://eloquera.com/).

Comment: +1 for Eloquera. It can work in the embedded mode, and serializes the objects of any complexity with no need for the [Serializable] attribute.

Comment: As  init corrections: you **do not** require a parameterless constructor - ctor skipping is supported. And: you don't need an attributes such as DataContractAttribute - there is a separate API for configuring types without using attributes, ideal for types that you don't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

The [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552.aspx) class does not require an object to be marked as serializable, but it only saves the public fields and properties. If you need to serialize the private members, you are out of luck unless you write your own serializer.

Comment: BinaryFormatter will throw exception until each member of serialization target is marked by [Serializable]

Comment: Anyway the XmlSerializer do not require [Serializable] and can be used to serialize.